# GROUP BY in sub query: slow. Using views helps, but can this be done in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, subquery

Running this query takes a long time:

```
SELECT host,ip FROM arecords WHERE ip IN 
   (SELECT ip FROM arecords GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip)>1 )
;
```

(In my arecords table, sometimes there is more than one host on a IP. For these cases, I want to get the hostname+ip)

I have the feeling the sub query is run a lot of times. If I run the sub query, take the results, and replace the sub query with these results, it is fast. I found I can avoid this by using views.

**Is there a way of doing it with one query?**

[Example SQLfiddle of the result I'd like: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c1bd/1/0 ]

Comment: The combination is unique, yes.

Comment: @Karlo : see my updated answer now... I believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution. This will retrieve all rows for each ip that exists in the table more than once. This uses a subselect in `FROM`, which is executed once — rather than a subquery in a `WHERE` which gets executed once for each outer row.

After the `ip`s are selected, you join on the same table where the `ip` is equal to the `ip` that was selected in the `FROM` subselect. The join should be fast as it will happen over indexes and the final result is that it will get `host`s + `ip`s for only the `ip`s having more than one value in the table:

```
SELECT 
    b.host,
    b.ip
FROM
    (
        SELECT ip
        FROM arecords
        GROUP BY ip
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    arecords b ON a.ip = b.ip AND b.active = 'T'
```

Comment: This looks good. I left out a small detail, I only want records where `active`='T'. Where do I put the WHERE? Not just before the inner join...?

Comment: To make my comment more clear, I want the output like the following link, but without host03: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64a5a/2/0

Comment: You can put it as a second condition in the `INNER JOIN`. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT host,ip 
FROM arecords ar 
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
    FROM arecords ex
    WHERE ex.ip = ar.ip
    AND ex.host <> ar.host
    )
    ;
```